# What does setScaledContents means in Qt?

Tags: qt

What does setScaledContents means ?  Read Qt's manual , I did not understand it well.. And when it we need to be set to true、 As follow:

```
        lbLogo = new QLabel(this);
        lbLogo->setFixedSize(BUTTON_SIZE);
        lbLogo->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/NotePad.png"));
        //lbLogo->setScaledContents(true);
```

**Qt: libpng warning: Interlace handling should be turned on when using png_read_image**

Thank you~

Answer:
This is a bug...  information from:  http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/44544-Qt-4-7-4-problem-with-libpng

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It scales the image of the label so that the image fits the label, not bigger or smaller.

Comment: firstly, Thank you .. And if the image is jpg,, then it can be set false... If it is png , then it must be set true. Why /

Comment: You're welcome. You can set it true or false anyway but I honestly don't know why it's supposed to be  set true for the pngs especially.

Comment: Yeah, I have found some information about it. It is a bug...  http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/44544-Qt-4-7-4-problem-with-libpng